# How to create a case sensitive Hashtable without generating a PSScriptAnalyzer warning?

Tags: powershell, hashtable, case-sensitive, psscriptanalyzer

By default hash tables created by PowerShell (e.g. `$hashtable = @{}`) are case insensitive.

For my script I want to explicitly create a ***case sensitive*** hash table.

This can be done by:

```
$hashtable = [hashtable]::new()
```

or:

```
$hashtable = New-Object hashtable
```

But I want to have my script also compliant with the default [PSScriptAnalyzer](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/tree/development/RuleDocumentation) rules. For the above case sensitive hash table examples, the [UseLiteralInitializerForHashtable](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/UseLiteralInitializerForHashtable.md) rule cases a warning:

> Use literal initializer, @{{}}, for creating a hashtable as they are case-insensitive by default

I would expect to be able to work arround this by specifying the `StringComparer`, like:

```
[HashTable]::New(0, [StringComparer]::Ordinal)
```

But this still generates an error (although `[HashTable]::New(0, [StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)` doesn't).
<sub>AFAIK, there is not something like: `[StringComparer]::OrdinalMatchCase`, or?</sub>

How to create a case sensitive Hashtable without generating a PSScriptAnalyzer warning?

PSScriptAnalyzer version: `1.18.3`
Tested both Windows PowerShell (`5.1`) and PowerShell Core (`6.2.3`)

**Steps to reproduce the warning:**

```
Invoke-ScriptAnalyzer -ScriptDefinition '[HashTable]::New(0, [StringComparer]::Ordinal)'
```

Comment: [HashTable]::New(0, [StringComparer]::Ordinal) is working here without any error. Which PS Version are you using?

Comment: For info, the PS plugin for VScode doesn't complain about any of those formats.

Comment: I have added some version information and steps to reproduce the warning to the question.

Comment: i  _vaguely_ recall reading that you can add PSSA instructions in your file. that would let you tell it to ignore the specified rule for that one file. i suspect you can do the same for the workspace ... but i have not been able to find any docs on the idea. [*blush*]

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions, I guess I was actually for a confirmation that I didn't overlook something obvious in this. I have created a PSScriptAnalyser issue enhancement request: [#1858](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/issues/1385)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to encapsulate the hashtable using inline c# as a custom static class?

```
Add-Type -typedef @"
    using System;
    using System.Collections;

    namespace myCsharp 
    {
        //-----------------------------------------
        public class myHashtable
        //-----------------------------------------
        {

            //-------------------------------------
            public static Hashtable GetHashtable()
            //-------------------------------------
            {
                Hashtable ht = new Hashtable( 0, StringComparer.Ordinal);
                return ht;
            }

        }
    }
"@

$x = [myCsharp.myHashtable]::GetHashtable()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Although this technically works, it is far off from the actual PSScriptAnalyzer goal to create lean PowerShell scripts...